# C++ Member class declaration in one file. Implementation in another

Tags: c++, standards, c++98

I would like to know if the process I'll explain below is considered as being standard c++ 98.

In fact, I have an A class that has a private member class called B. To have everything easier to read and more logical, I want to have the declaration of my A class in A.h and of my B class in B.h. As well, I want the implementation of my A class to be in A.cpp and my implementation of my B class in B.cpp.

Below are the files I used to have everything compiled (without any problem) under VS2012 and GCC. I didn't include the inclusion guards in the .h files here for readability reasons.

Thanks in advance for your help.

----------------------------   A.h   --------------------------------------------

```
class A
{
public:
    A();
    void printFromB();
    void createB();
private:
    class B;
    B* b;
};

#include "B.h"
```

----------------------------   B.h   --------------------------------------------

```
#include <iostream>

class A;

class A::B
{
public:
    void print();
};
```

----------------------------   A.cpp   --------------------------------------------

```
#include "A.h"

A::A(){}

void A::printFromB() {
    b->print();
}

void A::createB(){
    b = new B;
}
```

----------------------------   B.cpp   --------------------------------------------

```
#include "A.h"

using namespace std;

void A::B::print()
{
        cout << endl << "B prints!" << endl;
}
```

--------------------------   main.cpp   ------------------------------------------

```
#include "A.h"

int main()
{
    A a;
    a.createB();
    a.printFromB();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That `B.h` is a bit pointless since it can't be included separately from `A.h` - you need the full definition of `A`, not just a declaration, to use the nested type name `B`. Apart from that, I don't see anything obviously dodgy - but I don't see an answerable question either. What specific problem or doubt do you have with this code?

Comment: Yes, this is conforming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing illegal about your code.

By definition you will never use `class B` without `class A`.

But then it is that very definition which asks the question, "Then why bother creating a separate file?"
Since this is your project though, you do it how you want.